# Is there a 'friction-free' way of converting a RAID1 to a RAID5?

Tags: raid, mdadm, storage

What's the best way to convert a Linux software (that is, `mdadm`) RAID1 array to a RAID5 array? If the procedure is different for the cases of 3-disk RAID5 vs. 4-disk RAID5, how is it different?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Before doing anything of this sort *back up your data to separate media* and *verify the backup* via `sha1sum`.

The general procedure from there would look like:

- Add the third drive to your system.
- Create a degraded RAID5 out of the new drive and the one freed from the RAID1.
- Copy the data over to the RAID5 volume.
- Add the RAID1 disk to the RAID5 volume, and give it plenty of time to synchronize itself properly.
- Verify that the data on the new volume matches the backup.

Also refer to [kernel.org's Wiki page on mdadm](https://raid.wiki.kernel.org/index.php?title=A_guide_to_mdadm&oldid=5907#Raid_5), and, for the opposite direction (RAID6 to RAID1, at least), there's [a question on serverfault.com](https://serverfault.com/questions/178241/raid-6-to-raid-1-with-mdadm), where one of the answer also mentions [a blog post about mdadm level changes](http://neil.brown.name/blog/20090817000931).

Comment: You may also want to make offerings to whatever deity you believe in before beginning this process.

Comment: So it's possible to do without a 4th hard drive, thanks.

Comment: Didn't realise you could create a degraded raid5 with only 2 drives!

Comment: I'd feel better about upvoting if you could provide the `mdadm` commands for each step.

Comment: Also, come to think of it, it's completely unneccessary (and dangerous) nowadays to break the RAID1 mirroring. Removed that point of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Many nice RAID controllers can take a RAID 1 array, and when you add another drive, allow you to convert it on the fly to RAID5, of course, now twice the size.

The AMI/LSI based controllers have been doing this for a few years (is it a decade yet?).  Dell PERC's, Compaq/HP's Smart Array controllers have often used these chipsets.